# Получить RGB из System.Windows.Media.Brush

Tags: c#, wpf, color

Как получить RGB значения из `System.Windows.Media.Brush` объекта ?

Comment: Так ведь кисть не обязана быть однородной. О каком RGB речь?

Comment: @alexolut один цвет

Comment: Что "один цвет"? :) Кисти, говорю, разные могут быть, хоть картинками всё залить можно [например](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.media.imagebrush(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Кисть не обязательно одноцветная. Если она на деле одноцветная, попробуйте скастить в `SolidColorBrush`.

Comment: @alexolut ну залить нужно не картинкой) а одним цветом состоящим из R - G и B.

Comment: Если она одноцветная, то после рекомендаций @VladD просто запросить свойство `Color`. А дальше у `Color` уже есть компоненты отдельно доступные.

Comment: @VladD что означает `скастить` ?

Comment: @Сергей: ну это как в ответе

Comment: @VladD понял. привести к типу

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if (brush is SolidColorBrush solid)
{
    var r = solid.Color.R;
    var g = solid.Color.G;
    var b = solid.Color.B;
}
```

Используя старый синтаксис:

```
var solid = brush as SolidColorBrush;
if (solid != null)
{
    var r = solid.Color.R;
    var g = solid.Color.G;
    var b = solid.Color.B;
}
```

Comment: А такой синтаксис давно в шарпах? Имеется в виду определение переменной внутри условия.

Comment: @alexolut недавно, с версии c#7

Comment: @alexolut 7 марта 2017 года вышла Visual Studio 2017 с поддержкой c#7

Comment: @alexolut: очень удобно, кстати

Comment: @RusArt Спасибо, разобрался!